# Yielding spellchecker

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocorrect

The title is a bit misleading maybe; my spellchecker focuses more on format than spelling (caps, punctuation and spaces, apostrophes, converting internet slang to full words, oft-scrambled words etc.). However the basic principles apply.

Basically, the JS/jQuery checker I'm building would correct words as they are typed (after a space or punctuation has been typed after the word).

However, much like any autocorrecting, it's bound to run into mistakes. I'm not even considering creating functionality that would determine whether "its" or "it's" is more appropriate in a given case (though if such a plugin or code snippet exists, do point me to one).

So I want to make it a "yielding" autocorrect (for the lack of the knowledge of a better name). Basically;

1. User types in a word that would set off the checker, and types a
   space.
2. The checker corrects the word.
3. The user deems this a mistake
   and corrects it back (by Backspacing the whole word, or parts of it,
   or highlighting it or however they feel comfortable editing it).
4. The
   user continues typing, and the checker doesn't touch that instance of that word again.

Now easiest of course would be to disable the check for that word entirely, but I want the checker to correct future instances of it. What I'm looking for would detect a user editing an autocorrected word (regardless whether right after typing or later) back to what it was before being autocorrected, and then learning to leave that specific instance of that word alone.

I don't even know where to begin with this. I'm thinking a contenteditable with each word wrapped in a span, autocorrected ones having a special class and a data-* attribute containing the original one, listen for edits on the autocorrected words, and if it's edited back to equaling the data-* value, add a class that leaves it out of future autocorrect rounds.

I'm thinking though that this might be unnecessarily complicated, or at least not the path of least resistance. What would be the smartest way of doing this?

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me. Do you search for an contenteditable alternative or what is it that makes you doubt?

Comment: I'm always doubting my own approaches to things. Seems like keeping track of these spans, especially when the content is edited or deleted in the middle, might get messy.

Comment: For what it's worth, I do not appreciate when my typing is autocorrected for me. Yeah, it's a hassle to manually fix things that I misspell, but all too often automatic corrections are not even close to what I intended, and I don't notice until I'm several words away (because I touch type at 90 wpm+). This system would be super annoying to me. Better to let me see there's a problem and evaluate.

Comment: @ErikE totally agreed, this system is not for everyone, an option to disable it is a must. That reminds me of the different ways you can input, for instance, Japanese text in a text editor: either you type each word in Hiragana, converts it to Kanji, then move to the next word, repeat; or you type a whole sentence or paragraph in Hiragana then proceed to convert it word to word in rapid succession. Fast typers would indeed prefer the latter, and IMHO that applies to spell checking as well.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not building a spellchecker per se; I too find them annoying in their inaccuracy, not to mention it would be redundant, since browsers generally have their own built-in checkers. What I want to do is fix errors in punctuation, caps, etc. - language style corrections which are often not up to one's opinions or preferences, and I'd venture, easier for an autocorrect to get right. However, I am a big supporter of customizing, so users would have a choice between autocorrection, error highlighting and nothing at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your suggested approach (separating each word in a `span` and storing additional data in it) at first glance seems to be the most sensible approach. On the editor level, you just need to ensure all text is inside some `span`, and that each of them contains only a single word (splitting it if necessary). On the word level, just listen for changes in the `span`s (binding `input` and `propertyChange`) and act according to its class/data.

However, the real pain is to keep the **caret** position consistent. When you change the contents of either a `textarea` or an element with `contentEditable`, the caret moves rather unpredictably, and there's no easy (cross-browser) way of keeping track of the caret. I searched for solutions both here at SO and elsewhere, and the simplest working solution I found was [this blog post](http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/). Unfortunatly it only applied to `textarea`, so the "each word in a span" solution couldn't be used.

So, I suggest the following approach:

- Keep a list of words in an `Array`, where each word stores both the current value and the original;
- When the contents of the `textarea` changes, keep the set of unchanged words and redo the rest;
- Only apply the spell check if the caret is just after a non-word character (room for improvement) and you're not hitting `backspace`;
- If the user was unsatisfied with the correction, hitting `backspace` once will undo it, and it won't be checked again **unless modified**.

  - If many corrections were done at once (for instance, if a lot of text were copy-pasted), each `backspace` will undo one correction until no one is left.
  - Hitting any other key will commit the correction, so if the user is still unsatisfied he'll have to go back and change it again.
  - Note: differently from the OP requirements, the changed version **will** be autocorrected again if the user inputs a non-word character; he'll need to hit `backspace` once to "protect" it.

I created a simple proof-of-concept at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/VkENt/). Details below. Note that you can combine it with other approaches (for instance, detecting a "down arrow" key and displaying a menu with some auto-correcting options) etc.

---

Steps of the [proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/VkENt/) explained in detail:

- Keep a list of words in an `Array`, where each word stores both the current value and the original;

  ```
  var words = [];
  ```

  This regex splits the text into words (each word has a `word` property and a `sp` one; the latter stores non-word characters immediatly following it)

  ```
  delimiter:/^(\w+)(\W+)(.*)$/,
  ...
  regexSplit:function(regex,text) {
      var ret = [];
      for ( var match = regex.exec(text) ; match ; match = regex.exec(text) ) {
          ret.push({
              word:match[1],
              sp:match[2],
              length:match[1].length + match[2].length
          });
          text = match[3];
      }
      if ( text )
          ret.push({word:text, sp:'', length:text.length});
       return ret;
  }
  ```
- When the contents of the `textarea` changes, keep the set of unchanged words and redo the rest;

  ```
      // Split all the text
      var split = $.autocorrect.regexSplit(options.delimiter, $this.val());
      // Find unchanged words in the beginning of the field
      var start = 0;
      while ( start < words.length && start < split.length ) {
          if ( !words[start].equals(split[start]) )
              break;
          start++;
      }
      // Find unchanged words in the end of the field
      var end = 0;
      while ( 0 < words.length - end && 0 < split.length - end ) {
          if ( !words[words.length-end-1].equals(split[split.length-end-1]) ||
               words.length-end-1 < start )
              break;
          end++;
      }
      // Autocorrects words in-between
      var toSplice = [start, words.length-end - start];
      for ( var i = start ; i < split.length-end ; i++ )
          toSplice.push({
              word:check(split[i], i),
              sp:split[i].sp,
              original:split[i].word,
              equals:function(w) {
                  return this.word == w.word && this.sp == w.sp;
              }
          });
      words.splice.apply(words, toSplice);
      // Updates the text, preserving the caret position
      updateText();
  ```
- Only apply the spell check if the caret is just after a non-word character (room for improvement) and you're not hitting `backspace`;

  ```
  var caret = doGetCaretPosition(this);
  var atFirstSpace = caret >= 2 &&
                     /\w\W/.test($this.val().substring(caret-2,caret));
  function check(word, index) {
      var w = (atFirstSpace && !backtracking ) ?
              options.checker(word.word) :
              word.word;
      if ( w != word.word )
          stack.push(index); // stack stores a list of auto-corrections
      return w;
  }
  ```
- If the user was unsatisfied with the correction, hitting `backspace` once will undo it, and it won't be checked again **unless modified**.

  ```
  $(this).keydown(function(e) {
      if ( e.which == 8 ) {
          if ( stack.length > 0 ) {
              var last = stack.pop();
              words[last].word = words[last].original;
              updateText(last);
              return false;
          }
          else
              backtracking = true;
          stack = [];
      }
  });
  ```
- The code for `updateText` simply joins all words again into a string, and set the value back to the `textarea`. The caret is preserved if nothing was changed, or placed just after the last autocorrection done/undone, to account for changes in the text length:

  ```
  function updateText(undone) {
      var caret = doGetCaretPosition(element);
      var text = "";
      for ( var i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++ )
          text += words[i].word + words[i].sp;
      $this.val(text);
      // If a word was autocorrected, put the caret right after it
      if ( stack.length > 0 || undone !== undefined ) {
          var last = undone !== undefined ? undone : stack[stack.length-1];
          caret = 0;
          for ( var i = 0 ; i < last ; i++ )
              caret += words[i].word.length + words[i].sp.length;
          caret += words[last].word.length + 1;
      }
      setCaretPosition(element,caret);
  }
  ```
- The final plugin structure:

  ```
  $.fn.autocorrect = function(options) {
      options = $.extend({
          delimiter:/^(\w+)(\W+)(.*)$/,
          checker:function(x) { return x; }
      }, options);
      return this.each(function() {
          var element = this, $this = $(this);
          var words = [];
          var stack = [];
          var backtracking = false;
          function updateText(undone) { ... }
          $this.bind("input propertyChange", function() {
              stack = [];
              // * Only apply the spell check if the caret...
              // * When the contents of the `textarea` changes...
              backtracking = false;
          });
          // * If the user was unsatisfied with the correction...
      });
  };
  $.autocorrect = {
      regexSplit:function(regex,text) { ... }
  };
  ```

Comment: What a fun project you so luckily had time to play with!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're only submitting the word left of the caret, could you disable the spellchecker until a whitespace character is typed or the textbox caret is moved?

I'm not sure if that's the kind of answer you wanted.